# Copy Windows 7 recovery partition to a bootable external drive

Tags: windows-7, boot

I would like to copy my netbook recovery parition to a bootable external HDD because two of my partitions were damaged including the partition which contained the Master Boot Record.
I wasn't able to repair the mbr but I needed the machine so I installed a Win 8 on it but now I want to reinstall the factory win 7 which is on the offline recovery partition but I don't know how can I copy it to a bootable drive.

Comment: you should be able to use the same MBR that Win 8 uses.

Answer (score 1):

You could use clonezilla, it's a live-Linux for cloning partitions and drives. It its possible to clone a partition directly from one device (netbook HDD) to another device (external HDD).

[Official clonezilla website](http://clonezilla.org/)

Comment: Can i make the copy bootable with clonezilla? because I said the mbr was damaged. Or does the recovery image contain the necessary boot files?

Comment: I think clonezilla itself is not usable to create a MBR; I just found [Parted Magic(http://partedmagic.com), which also contains gparted for partitioning and install-mbr for creating a MBR.

The recovery image should contain boot files, but the partition information is stored in the MBR.

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is copy it over to the External HDD and then use something like `Hiren's BootCD` or something similar to boot the computer to the External HDD,  it's been a while since I messed with that stuff, but I remember that there is a way to boot up and then it asks you what Disk you want to boot up into or something similar to that.