# How do I back up my laptop's Restore Partition to a bootable CD?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, partition-recovery

My laptop has a 1.5GB recovery partition. The hard drive is getting old and I'd like to back up this partition so I can put it on a new hard drive if I ever need to. Is there a way to back up a recovery partition to a DVD or another file format that can be loaded onto a HD in the future?

Comment: Some laptops come with a preinstalled application which allows you to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy Windows 7 recovery partition to a bootable external drive](http://superuser.com/questions/634319/copy-windows-7-recovery-partition-to-a-bootable-external-drive), [transfer my laptops recovery partition keeping it bootable](http://superuser.com/questions/691773/transfer-my-laptops-recovery-partition-keeping-it-bootable)